# Simply counting each time a button is clicked - Ext JS

Tags: button, extjs, if-statement, count

So I have the #add_button in my main app.js:

```
{ xtype: 'button', text: 'Add', itemId: 'add_criteria' }
```

I have the controller here that is listens for each click and attempts to add 1 each time the #add_button is clicked:

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Add', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#add_button': {
                click: this.add
            }
        });
    },

    add: function(btn) {
        var count = 0;
        if (count <= 3)
        {
            count++;
            console.log('Count is now ' + count;

        }
        else {
            console.log('wut');
        }

    }
});
```

The controller is set up properly, however I can't seem to keep a count on the number of times clicked. It's telling me it's 'undefined'. Any ideas?

And yes I've seen the Sencha docs on the 'button' component. I, however am handling the event with a controller.

Comment: Where are you getting undefined?  The console.log call?

Comment: Your logic for `count` doesn't make sense. It will always reset to zero on every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `count` as a local variable, and initializing it to 0 every time your button is clicked.  You need to make `count` a member variable of the controller.

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Add', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.control({
            '#add_button': {
                click: this.add
            }
        });
    },

    add: function(btn) {
        if (this.count <= 3)
        {
            this.count++;
            console.log('Count is now ' + this.count);

        }
        else {
            console.log('wut');
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfect, but doesn't seem to adhere to the layout (hbox) of my panel. How could I get it to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here... what does the controller have to do with your hbox layout?

Comment: The handler adds a combobox to my panel, that's great. But it's not aligned with the comboboxes already rendered inside the panel.

Comment: Sounds like a different & unrelated problem, you may want to debug for a while and make a new post (with code) if you're unable to figure that one out.